# Correct way to use socket.on in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, web-crawler

I am working on a small project which will be used for crawling. I am having problem while working with sockets.
I am emitting some events from the server in a loop.

```
for(i=0;i<blogs.length;i++){

        socket.emit('crawling',blogs[i]);

        const startTime = Date.now();
        const post = await crawlPost(blogs[i]);
        const endTime = Date.now();

        socket.emit('crawled',blogs[i]);
        socket.emit('timeTaken',{
            time: endTime-startTime,
            blog : blogs[i],
        });
    }
```

I want to listen for these events one by one in react component, but I am unable to do so, code I have written for listening to the events.

```
const App = () => {
    const [crawlingBlog, setCrawlingBlog] = useState([]);
    const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:4000';
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);

    useEffect(() => {

      socket.on('crawling' , (blog) => {
        setCrawlingBlog(crawlingBlog.concat(blog))
      })

    },[])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you wrap your socket at the server like that?

```
module.exports = connectSockets

function connectSockets(io) {
    io.on('connection', socket => {

        for(i=0;i<blogs.length;i++){

        socket.emit('crawling',blogs[i]);

        const startTime = Date.now();
        const post = await crawlPost(blogs[i]);
        const endTime = Date.now();

        socket.emit('crawled',blogs[i]);
        socket.emit('timeTaken',{
            time: endTime-startTime,
            blog : blogs[i],
        });
    }


    })
}
```